# How many generation will it take for the wild genes of the cows to resurface?

Tags: biology

Cows have been carefully selected in the past 10000 years in order to domesticate them. Except for few cases like the breeds for corrida bulls the unruly ones were the first ones to be slaughtered and the ones friendly to their human keepers were kept and allowed to breed.

But that requirement might soon disappear. In the near future there could be robotic farms where the cattle see very little the human keepers. Selection rules will be based only on productivity. Might the ancient wild genes resurface?

How many generations of cattle should pass before we begin to see news of the kind: *Robotic farm paralysed by software bug. Escaped cows kill  x people and injure y*?

Comment: I don't know about your robotic farms, but people get killed by livestock all the time. Which "ancient wild genes"?  What's the worldbuilding question here, the problem to solve? (Be aware we don't predict the future, much.) In addition, you might want to research the habits of wild cattle. Whilst bulls can rampage when provoked, cows herd for protection rather than roaming solitary.

Comment: *"but people get killed by livestock all the time."* Given the mass and the muscles they have that is not a surprise. But except few occasional outbursts they are quite friendly towards humans. Definitely the ancient Aurochs were not so friendly. But I know that not only we have corrida breeds, but also a nazi leader created by selection a breed of aggressive livestock in his own private farm (I am missing online references though), such examples might give an idea of how many generations  might take to loose a behavioural trait.

Comment: [Heck cattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heck_cattle). How many generations were needed?

Comment: @AlexP Is an intentional effort to re-breed the original animal a valid reference for this question? If the Heck Cattle were simply released into the wild, it's highly unlikely those results would have occurred in the time they did.

Comment: VTC: (a) This appears to be a Real World question asking about the consequences of Real World decisions and not a worldbuilding question at all. (b) [Feral cattle](https://www.latimes.com/local/california/la-me-feral-bulls-20180302-story.html) are a problem today, and yet it appears you've done no research into that. (c) Your question assumes that all modern breeds have the same hereditary path back to the original herd. This isn't true. Without specifying which breed the question is too broad.

Comment: (d) You also seem to be assuming that the presence of humans is what makes cows docile. Without knowing the nature of your robotic farm, it's impossible to gauge if the cows can even go feral, much less have a reversion back to their wild genetics. Why do you believe that robotic farming would result in cessation of animal husbandry?

Comment: @JBH: *Those* results, no. Extant feral cattle are very diverse, but do not look like the Heck cattle. The WP article on the [Chillingham cattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillingham_cattle) in England has pictures.

Answer (score 5):

## Based on productivity? Ideally never.

Your future farms where humans aren't present and cattle is selected solely on productivity with no concerns for aggressiveness may sound like an ideal place for animals to become more violent, but what we really got to do is see how this machine farm environment is like.

Since we're talking about futuristic technology and about increasing productivity as much as possible, ironically the cows might actually become more docile. The truth is that when you want a good cow farm, you don't want them to be treated poorly or inhumanely, quite the opposite. Cows that are stressed, unhappy and that walk a lot (in case of cattle for human consumption) offer overall worse products than those who aren't, because these things affects their health and the quality of their meat, and so an ideal robot farm seeking to maximize productivity wants to ensure cows are always kept in an environment where they're mostly calm and content, not needing to walk long distances to get food and with, ideally, no worries about any threat or major stressing factors.

This kind of environment does somewhat exist naturally already: Islands with no predators. We've seen a good number of cases where animals that lived in environments with no natural predators essentially evolved not to fear most things. This is seen in certain species of animals, like the quokka and the now extinct dodo, which were so accustomed to an environment with no real threats available that they simply stopped fearing, casually approaching never before seen humans like it was just another day (as a result, one group is threatened while the other is extinct). This doesn't only apply to prey though: animals like the harpy eagle also have no natural predators, and other than when protecting their young, usually do not attack nor fear humans, which becomes a problem for them when a few rotten members of our species decide to hunt harpies for fun (they're also threatened).

That is not to say a response to predators can't re-appear. We've done experiments involving inserting predators in places where were none, and the ultimate result is that prey species either adapt or die off, with members more capable of avoiding the predators usually being selected.

So overall, your scenario probably wouldn't cause aggressive cows to rise against humanity, given the basic premise of maximizing productivity. With that goal, you want the cows to never need to worry about a thing and to live mostly healthy and fulfilling lives so they can offer better products, and if selective breeding does happen to produce agitated and angry cows that are overall more stressed on a daily basis, that genetic line will probably be swiftly ended, because an angry cow is a stressed cow that can also stress the others, and that's not what you want here.

If however humans do start seeing hyperagressive cattle being released left and right due to "software bugs", chances are it's not aggressive genes resurfacing accidentally as much as it is Skynet™ testing out the potential of bovine warfare against humanity.